# scatter plots for all pairwise columns between two data frames

Tags: r

lets say I have 2 data frames:

```
df1 = data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), c = rnorm(10))
df2 = data.frame(d = rnorm(10), e = rnorm(10))
```

I would like to look at the all pairwise scatter plots **between** data frames:

i.e.: the six scatter plots: a vs d, a vs e, b vs d, b vs e, c vs d, c vs e.

How could I achieve this? I notice that `pairs` does this for a single `data.frame`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `cbind` to combine the two dfs and then use `plot()`

```
df1 = data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), c = rnorm(10))
df2 = data.frame(d = rnorm(10), e = rnorm(10))


df <- cbind(df1, df2)

plot(df)
```

[image]

If you want to create only plots between the two `data.frames` (no self comparison), you can loop them:

```
par(mfrow = c(ncol(df1), ncol(df2)))


for(i in 1:ncol(df1)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(df2)){
    plot(df1[,i], df2[,j], main = paste(names(df1)[i], "vs", names(df2)[j]), 
         ylab = names(df2)[j], 
         xlab = names(df1)[i])
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: or just `c(df1,df2)`

Answer (score 2):

A pretty (unnecessarily complicated?) tidyverse/ggplot2 solution.

Reorganize data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mfun <- function(x,label="df1") {
    x %>%
      mutate(obs=seq(n())) %>%    ## add obs numbers
      gather(key=var,value=value,-obs)  ## reshape
}
## combine
df12 <- mfun(df1) %>% full_join(mfun(df2),by="obs")
```

Plot:

```
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(df12,aes(value.x,value.y)) +
    geom_point()+
    facet_grid(var.x~var.y)+
    theme(panel.margin=grid::unit(0,"lines")) ## squash panels together
```

[image]