# How to combine observed and simulated pairs plot in one plot for goodness fit

Tags: r

I am interesting in multivariate data. I used `pairs` to get the pairs plot of the data. I fitted a model to the data and in order to check the fit of the model to the data, I simulated from the fitted model. Then, I would like to combine the true plot of the data with the simulated data from the fitted model in one pairs plot. I tried this:

```
pairs(mydata)
point(simdata)
```

However, this does not give me what I want. 
This is the pairs plot of my data.

[image]

I want similar to this but with pairs plot.

[image]

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454681/scatter-plots-for-all-pairwise-columns-between-two-data-frames

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scatter plots for all pairwise columns between two data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454681/scatter-plots-for-all-pairwise-columns-between-two-data-frames)

Comment: No the question is not the same as my question. I would like to check my model fit using graphical tools. That is compare the plot of the true data and the data simulated from the fitted model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to stick with base R's `pairs`, you could try the following:

```
pairs(iris, col = iris$Species)
```

[image]

If you have two different datasets, the idea is the same. The only difference is that we need to create a variable that both datasets share so we can distinguish between them when using `col = df$some_variable`:

```
# Two different datasets
observed <- iris[1:75,]
simulated <- iris[76:150,]

# Adding 'observed' and 'simulated' values to a 'type' column
observed$type <- "observed"
simulated$type <- "simulated"

# Binding the observed and simulated dataset
df <- rbind(observed, simulated)

# Convert to factor
df$type <- as.factor(df$type)

# Plot
pairs(df, col = df$type)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your graph is the plot of the true data. Suppose that, I fit a `k-means` and estimate the model parameters. Then, I simulated from the fitted model. Then, I would like to plot the simulated data with the true data in the same plot.

Comment: I imagine that all you need to do is create a new column for both datasets so that you can distinguish between the two when using `col = df$new_column`. See my updated answer.

Comment: I will try your code with my data and will accept it once it solves my problem.

Comment: Good luck. If you get an error, please give me a minimal, reproducible example with `dput` and I'd be happy to modify my answer.